What's the most efficient brain–computer interface to play video games?
I read:

Technology for connecting paralyzed folks with computers has existed for a while now, according to Bloomberg:

Neuralink is not the only company working on brain devices that connect with computers. Modern demonstrations of cursor control by using thoughts have taken place in other humans with various types of implants, such as those deployed by the BrainGate consortium of research institutions and hospitals.
However, the Neuralink device contains more electrodes than other devices, suggesting it may have more potential applications in future. The Neuralink technology works without needing a wired connection to external devices.
[...]
“I’m happy for the individual that he’s been able to interface with a computer in a way he wasn’t able to before the implant,” said Kip Allan Ludwig, co-director of the Wisconsin Institute for Translational Neuroengineering. “That’s not a breakthrough compared to what others have shown previously, but it’s certainly a good starting point.”


This makes me wonder: What's the most efficient brain–computer interface to play video games?
By most efficient, I mean allowing players to play the best. One can objectively compare BCI devices, e.g. see the paper {1} section "BCI control in a realistic scenario: car racing", and one could consider different input factors such as latency, control accuracy and number of different input types.

References:

{1} Satyam Kumar, Hussein Alawieh, Frigyes Samuel Racz, Rawan Fakhreddine, José del R Millán, Transfer learning promotes acquisition of individual BCI skills, PNAS Nexus, Volume 3, Issue 2, February 2024, pgae076, https://doi.org/10.1093/pnasnexus/pgae076


I'm not sure this is in scope for this forum. It almost sounds like a product recommendation request.

Theoretically, using signals from the brain will be more efficient compared to any interface you can design, since it still requires you to convert signals from the brain into muscle movements and then transfer those actions to a controller.
I watched a video on @perrikaryal, who has trained herself to control games with her mind (or rather, brain signals) with games like Elden Ring, Halo and TrackMania all without using a controller. She uses an EEG (electroencephalogram) that picks up her brain activity, which then translates into pushing buttons on a virtual controller.
There are already motion controlled games that uses a camera to capture the action to bypass the additional input, and there are controllers that mimic real world objects that you can use like driving wheels and the Wii controller for playing sports games, which is not too different from real world scenarios.
I guess it depends on the type of games that you are playing, because I don't think it is always most efficient to map specific types of thoughts and brain signals to inputs that are organized specifically for this on the game interfaces. I can imagine Real Time Strategy games where you need to interact with many elements on the screen, and any brain-computer interface will need to understand the context in order to process the signals that are generated.
